# Windows Terminal Ctrl key not working

Tags: ssh, vim, openssh, windows-terminal

I have a Ubuntu machine on the internet. I've used Windows Terminal to open PowerShell then used the Windows ssh command to connect to the Ubuntu machine. Finally I ran vim on the remote machine.

I don't seem to be able to do any of the vim commands that involve the Ctrl key. For example Ctrl+v is not entering Visual Block mode. Is Windows Terminal or ssh somehow filtering out the Ctrl key? If so is there a way to stop it?

The Ctrl key is definitely working because if I press Ctrl and + the font gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Usually key issues are related to [terminfo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html).

In this case however, I believe you have a Windows keycapture on `cmd.exe` or `ps.exe`. Tmux also is another troublesome combination with these.

However, I’d recommend you try [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty).

Simply, Windows terminals currently, do not work well for many reasons. I assume you are using this version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal ? I think these issues are some of those that are planned to be resolved in this terminal sooner or later (fingers crossed)